# Converting an expression to a graph (block diagram )

Tags: graphs-and-networks, expression-manipulation, boolean-computation

I want to make a diagram of the expression  `block1 ∩ block2 ∩ (block31 ∪ block32) ∩ block4`, as in the image shown below.

This expression can be put into a Boolean form as

```
block1 && block2 && (block31 ||  block32) && block4
```

or

```
block1 * block2 * (block31 +  block32) * block4
```

We can understand it like minimal path from beginning of system to end of system.

http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/09/30/reliability-mathematics-in-mathematica/

How can I convert such a Boolean expression to a list of graph edges for the below diagram?

```
edges = 
  {block1 \[DirectedEdge] block2, 
   block2 \[DirectedEdge] block31, block2 \[DirectedEdge] block32 , 
   block32 \[DirectedEdge] block4, block31 \[DirectedEdge] block4};

Graph[edges, 
  ImagePadding -> 10, 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square"]
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. What do you have already?  What details do not match?  What very often happens with questions like this is that someone writes a long answer reproducing the details of the diagram, then the original asker says that that's not exactly what they wanted. Or that they already had 90% of that ready but some critical (and difficult) detail is still missing. So please be very specific in your question and ask about the details you couldn't solve on your own.

Comment: Put all this information into the question itself (use the "edit" link below your post), not into comments.  Explain what is unsatisfactory in the output you get form your code.  Also, do look up `Graph`.

Comment: You certainly did not make the diagram you show with the code you post. The code does not work.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you need to tell us how you would represent the expression `block1 ∩ block2 ∩ (block3 ∪ block3) ∩ block4` in Mathematica. Without knowing that, I can not even begin to tackle your problem.

Comment: How would `a || b` get translated?  Do you assume that there is always a `start` and `end` so this would be `start && (a || b) && end`?

Comment: `&&` represents "AND", `||` represents "OR", block= TRUE   represents functional block, block = FALSE represents  dysfunctional block,  expression represents all possible paths from the beginning to the end.

Comment: could use BooleanMinimize if only contain Or and And...Graph[Union[
  Flatten[List @@ (DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[List @@ #, 2, 1] & /@ 
      BooleanMinimize[
       block1 && block2 && (block31 || block32) && block4])]]]